# What is wrong about this code using Transaction Management in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,timeout=1000, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
void saveUserAndHoliday(User user, Holiday holiday)
{
    // At this point vacationDays of user is 27
    userDao.save(user); 
    // here vacationDays of user is 24
    holiday.setOvertime(null);
    holidayDao.save(holiday);
    //here exception is thrown so I would expect vacationsDays be rolled back to 27
}
```

What is missing so my transaction would work.

So I just found out that method with Transaction must be in own class and also method should be public. But somehow still it does not work in my case. I really start getting annoyed.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    UserDao userDao;

    HolidayDao holidayDao;

    public MyService(UserDao userDao, HolidayDao holidayDao)
    {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.holidayDao = holidayDao;
    }

    @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,timeout=1000, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void saveUserAndHoliday(User user, Holiday holiday)
    {
        userDao.save(user);     
        holiday.setOvertime(null);
        holidayDao.save(holiday);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alicia17. Could you please take a bit more time to write your post and be a bit more specific ? Who is the client of your code (controller, service) ? What kind of application are you building ? Is it Spring only ? spring-boot maybe ? What did you try to make it work ? Also, what kind of DB are you using ? MySQL, Postgrel ? H2 ?Thanks.

Comment: If you use method inside the service where method is located @Transaction does not work

Comment: I am using Spring only. It's in the controller, a private method

Answer (score 2):

Several possible reasons that it does not work as expected.

1. `holidayDao.save(holiday)` start another new transaction using `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)`, so the holiday change was already committed when the exception is thrown.
2. You are self-invoke `saveUserAndHoliday()` which `@Transaction` will not take effect when invoke in this way . Also, it only applies to the methods with public visibility. (See the section ['Method visibility and @Transactional'](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for details)
3. You are using a database storage engine which does not support transaction such as MyISAM in MySQL.

Comment: this method is a private method or maybe package visible. It's only used in this controller class. Just for the sake of making it transactional , should I make it public. Sounds weird

Comment: What do you mean with number one ?

Comment: Yes. You should make the transactional method public , and must call it from another spring bean , this is how AOP (the technology that @transactional based on under the cover) work

Comment: In (1) , I mean the holidayDao.save() is also annotated with @transactional but configure it as REQUIRES_NEW , which mean another separate new transaction will start before this method execute and commit if it complete successfully.

Comment: as you can see above only saveUserAndHoliday is annoted with Transactional. Inside this method 2 DAO calls take place. First userDAO.save then holidayDAO.save .

Comment: yes. I know. but because you do not show the actual code of holidayDao.save() , so i do not know whether it is annotated with @transactional 's REQUIRES_NEW , so i  were guessing all the possible reasons ...

Comment: the code above is all I have. The DAO is not transactional.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Then you can discard my guess (1) and continues your troubleshoot ...

Comment: what you mean with "You are self-invoke saveUserAndHoliday()"

Comment: It means you are calling saveUserAndHoliday() from another method that is also within the same class

Comment: of course I call it from another method. That what functions are all about. I call it from a controller method

Comment: okay , good 。 then try to change it to public and try again

Comment: yes i will try tomorrow when I get back to work. But actually it is supposed to be private only called within class

Comment: so it will not work. make it public and call from another bean

Comment: aha. I only could outsource it to class Util and make it static there. I cannot move it to another bean .

Comment: static ? feel not so good from my gut feeling that it will not work too though i actually dont know what you are going to change。。。

Comment: the method is supposed to be private. Ok I will definitely leave it in this class. I just change from private to public. Will it work then ?

Comment: depend on what class call it. If it is called by another spring bean  , the chance for it to work after change to public is a little bit high

Comment: Ok you are right. @Transactional will only work over public methods, The method is in the same class where it is invoked. You need to have the method in a different class where the method is invoked.But why is all this. What is the reason why Transaction will not work otherwise.

Comment: It is explained in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)